# Problemas com ponteiro na função

Tags: c, array, funções, malloc

Estou tentando criar um vetor usando alocação de memória dentro de uma função e retornar esse vetor já preenchido para ser impresso através de outra função, mas acontece que os valores de dentro do vetor não estão sendo retornados e na hora de imprimir está sendo apresentado valores errados (lixo).

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void criar_vetor(int, int *);
void imprimir_vetor(int, int *);

int main()
{
    int tam, *vet1;
    srand(time(NULL));

    do
    {
        printf("Tamanho do vetor: ");
        scanf("%d", &tam);
    } while (tam <= 0);

    criar_vetor(tam, vet1);
    imprimir_vetor(tam, vet1);

    return 0;
}
void criar_vetor(int t, int *vet)
{
    int i;
    vet = (int *)malloc(t * sizeof(int));

    if (!vet)
    {
        printf("\nERRO!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < t; i++)
        vet[i] = rand() % 10;
}
void imprimir_vetor(int t, int *vet)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            printf("\nVetor = {%d, ", vet[i]);
        else if (i == t - 1)
            printf("%d}\n", vet[i]);
        else
            printf("%d, ", vet[i]);
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, Pedro!
Cara, pelo que eu vi do seu código, eu acredito que o problema seja o local de onde você está alocando a memória para o vetor. Faz pouco tempo que estudo programação, então posso estar falando besteira, mas se não estou errado, quando uma função termina o que ela tem que fazer, ela exclui todas as variáveis criadas dentro dela, então quando você chama a impressão depois de preencher, o vetor está "vazio". Eu testei aqui o seu código e se tu alocar a memória de dentro da função main funciona perfeitamente, outra forma é chamando a função de imprimir de dentro da função que preenche o vetor, assim, será impresso antes da função finalizar.

E está faltando a biblioteca stdio.h para funcionar as funções printf() e scanf().

Espero

Comment: Olá amigo, eu testei colocando a função imprimir dentro da função que preenche o vetor  e realmente funciona, mas acontece que eu estou usando ponteiros e fazendo a passagem de valor por referência, então pelo pouco entendimento que eu tenho deveria estar funcionando, mas obirgado pela dica de colocar a função dentro da outra!!! Valeu

Comment: Que bom que deu tudo certo aí! Então, quando usamos ponteiro, ele apenas aponta para uma região de memória, cabe ao programador alocar e desalocar após o uso, então quando tu reservou um espaço na memória de dentro da sua função, ela foi desalocada por assim dizer automaticamente quando a função encerrou, o seu ponteiro voltou a apontar para um endereço de memória novamente, já se você alocar a memória no main e mandar para a sua função ou qualquer outra coisa dentro do seu programa, o ponteiro vai continuar com os dados até que você libere aquela região de memória ou o programa finalize.

Comment: Não sei se tu está estudando por conta própria, mas se estiver, dá uma olhada num canal chamado Programe o seu futuro do professor Wagner Gaspar, ele explica bem e costuma tirar as dúvidas do pessoal nos comentários, e se estiver fazendo algum curso, vale a pena tirar a dúvida com o professor. Espero que ajude, até mais! ;)